# An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator in drop down list

Tags: ajax

when i am selecting values from dropdown list the corresponding values showing first time. but when i am again selecting the another value its not showing value instead of the error msg displaying **An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.** can anyone suggest me where i did wrong in the following code

```
<?php 

function form_test_menu() 
{
  $items['mark_entry'] = array(
    'title' => 'Mark Entry',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
  return $items;
}


function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) 
{

$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$batch = $_POST['batch'];
$month = $_POST['Month'];
$year = $_POST['Year'];
$semester = $_POST['semester'];

$query = db_select('student_master');
$query->fields('student_master', array('reg_no','name','dob','dept_code','degree','batch_year'));
$query->condition('dept_code',$dept,'=') AND $query->condition('batch_year',$batch,'=');
$results = $query->execute();
 $options = array();

foreach($results as $student_result)
{ 
$options[$student_result->reg_no]=t($student_result->reg_no);
} 

  $form['roll']= array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Registration Number'),
  '#options' =>$options,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array('callback' =>       '_ajaxfunction','wrapper' => 'subjectsdiv'),);

 $form['month'] = array('#title' => t('month'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $month,
'#required' => TRUE,);

 $form['year'] = array('#title' => t('year'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $year,
'#required' => TRUE,);

 $form['semester'] = array('#title' => t('semester'),
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $semester,
'#required' => TRUE,);

 $form['subjects'] = array('#prefix' => '<div id="subjectsdiv">','#suffix' => '</div>');

$form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit','#value' => 'Submit');

return $form;
}


function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state) 

{ 


$key = !empty($form_state['values']['roll']) ? $form_state['values']['roll'] : 1;

$month = !empty($form_state['values']['month']) ? $form_state['values']['month'] : 1;

$year = !empty($form_state['values']['year']) ? $form_state['values']['year'] : 1;

$semester = !empty($form_state['values']['semester']) ? $form_state['values']['semester'] : 1;

$query1 = db_select('semester_appear');
$query1->fields('semester_appear',array('subject_code'));
$query1->condition('reg_no',$key,'=') AND $query1->condition('semester_appear',$semester,'=')AND $query1->condition('month',$month,'=') AND $query1->condition('year',$year,'=');
$query1->orderBy('sub_serial_no','ASC');
$results = $query1->execute();

while ($record_res = $results->fetchAssoc())
{

$subject_name = $record_res['subject_code'];

$query = db_select('subject');
$query->fields('subject', array('subject_name','subject_code'));
$query->condition('subject_code',$subject_name,'=') ;
$subject_results = $query->execute();

foreach($subject_results as $sub_result)
{ 
$options[$sub_result->subject_code]=t($sub_result->subject_name);
}

  $form['subjects']['name']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Please Select Subject'),
    '#options' => $options,
'#required' => TRUE,);

$form['subjects']['inter'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('Internal Marks'), 
  '#size' => 60, 
  '#maxlength' => 128, 
  '#required' => TRUE,);


$form['subjects']['exter'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield', 
  '#title' => t('External Marks'), 
  '#size' => 60, 
  '#maxlength' => 128, 
  '#required' => TRUE,);

}

return $form['subjects']; 
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on which part of your code is causing the problem please? I doubt anyone's going to set up a site and form to match yours just to debug it for you - you're likely to get a much quicker/better answer if you narrow down where the problem is. Also, very importantly, if you're altering the form on the client side with Javascript you need to describe that too

Comment: I've answered your question here since it's a duplicate question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/resolve-the-error-an-illegal-choice-has-been-detected/125233#125233

Answer (score 1):

check for details in watchdog under `form` to get an indication of which form element is causing the grief - in your case it will be the 'roll' or subject name field (possibly both!)

if you are updating the option array and removing the currently set option, then you have 2 choices:

in your form builder, either

```
unset($form_state['input']['roll']);
```

or

```
$options[$form_state['values']['roll']] 
 = "the option i'm trying to get rid of";
```

the first option just discards the earlier selection, the latter option keeps it available (probably the first option is *generally* preferable)

additional: I've discovered I can also cause this error by messing my ajax call back so that the options are updated ok, but the form element in the browser isn't updated. In this case you will notice your options are not updating. You then need to double check your callbacks and div id's etc.

hth

Comment: @Bala - you are right - that is a very ordinary answer... sorry still struggling with it myself, but give me a minute :-0

Comment: hopefully that gets you going