# Illegal choice has been detected

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to develop this PhoneGap app to create a node of a specific type on a Drupal server. I got services installed, created endpoints and all. However when I tried, I got '`406: Not acceptable. Illegal operation detected`'. When I look at recent logs, I see a '`Not allowed value x`' and additional `Illegal offset type in isset or empty` for all my dropdowns. Any ideas how come?

**My HTML**

```
<div id="appHolder">
    <div id="topHolder">
        <div id="logoHolder">
            <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="titleHolder">Başvuru yap</div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentHolder" class="apply">
        <label for="profilepicture">Profil fotoğrafı</label>
        <input type="file" id="profilepicture" name="field_oyuncu_fotografi_value" />
        <div id="canvasparent">
            <img id="picture" />
            <canvas width="400" height="300" id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Adı & Soyadı" required name="title" />
        <input type="number" id="tckn" placeholder="TC Kimlik No" required name="field_tc_kimlik_no_value" />
        <select id="sgk" required name="field_sgk_durumu_value">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none">- SGK durumu -</option>
            <option value="devam_ediyor">Devam ediyor</option>
            <option value="emekli">Emekli</option>
        </select>
        <input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Telefon" required name="field_telefon_value" />
        <input type="tel" id="tel2" placeholder="Telefon 2" required name="field_telefon2_value" />
        <div class="description">Size ulaşamadığımız durumda ulaşabileceğimiz bir yakınınız</div>
        <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Adres" required name="field_adres_value" />
        <select id="city" required name="field_yasadigi_sehir_value">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Yaşadığı şehir -</option>
            <option value="01">Adana</option>
            <option value="02">Adıyaman</option>
            <option value="03">Afyon</option>
            <option value="04">Ağrı</option>
            <option value="05">Amasya</option>
            <option value="06">Ankara</option>
            <option value="07">Antalya</option>
            <option value="08">Artvin</option>
            <option value="09">Aydın</option>
            <option value="10">Balıkesir</option>
            <option value="11">Bilecik</option>
            <option value="12">Bingöl</option>
            <option value="13">Bitlis</option>
            <option value="14">Bolu</option>
            <option value="15">Burdur</option>
            <option value="16">Bursa</option>
            <option value="17">Çanakkale</option>
            <option value="18">Çankırı</option>
            <option value="19">Çorum</option>
            <option value="20">Denizli</option>
            <option value="21">Diyarbakır</option>
            <option value="22">Edirne</option>
            <option value="23">Elazığ</option>
            <option value="24">Erzincan</option>
            <option value="25">Erzurum</option>
            <option value="26">Eskişehir</option>
            <option value="27">Gaziantep</option>
            <option value="28">Giresun</option>
            <option value="29">Gümüşhane</option>
            <option value="30">Hakkari</option>
            <option value="31">Hatay</option>
            <option value="32">Isparta</option>
            <option value="33">Mersin</option>
            <option value="34">İstanbul</option>
            <option value="35">İzmir</option>
            <option value="36">Kars</option>
            <option value="37">Kastamonu</option>
            <option value="38">Kayseri</option>
            <option value="39">Kırklareli</option>
            <option value="40">Kırşehir</option>
            <option value="41">Kocaeli</option>
            <option value="42">Konya</option>
            <option value="43">Kütahya</option>
            <option value="44">Malatya</option>
            <option value="45">Manisa</option>
            <option value="46">K.Maraş</option>
            <option value="47">Mardin</option>
            <option value="48">Muğla</option>
            <option value="49">Muş</option>
            <option value="50">Nevşehir</option>
            <option value="51">Niğde</option>
            <option value="52">Ordu</option>
            <option value="53">Rize</option>
            <option value="54">Sakarya</option>
            <option value="55">Samsun</option>
            <option value="56">Siirt</option>
            <option value="57">Sinop</option>
            <option value="58">Sivas</option>
            <option value="59">Tekirdağ</option>
            <option value="60">Tokat</option>
            <option value="61">Trabzon</option>
            <option value="62">Tunceli</option>
            <option value="63">Şanlıurfa</option>
            <option value="64">Uşak</option>
            <option value="65">Van</option>
            <option value="66">Yozgat</option>
            <option value="67">Zonguldak</option>
            <option value="68">Aksaray</option>
            <option value="69">Bayburt</option>
            <option value="70">Karaman</option>
            <option value="71">Kırıkkale</option>
            <option value="72">Batman</option>
            <option value="73">Şırnak</option>
            <option value="74">Bartın</option>
            <option value="75">Ardahan</option>
            <option value="76">Iğdır</option>
            <option value="77">Yalova</option>
            <option value="78">Karabük</option>
            <option value="79">Kilis</option>
            <option value="80">Osmaniye</option>
        </select>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="E-posta" required name="field_e_posta_value" />
        <select id="gender" required name="field_cinsiyet_value">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Cinsiyet -</option>
            <option value="bay">Bay</option>
            <option value="bayan">Bayan</option>
        </select>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Kategorisi</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" id="oyuncu" name="field_kategorisi_value" value="oyuncu">Oyuncu
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cocuk_oyuncu" name="field_kategorisi_value" value="cocuk_oyuncu">Çocuk oyuncu
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yardimci_oyuncu" name="field_kategorisi_value" value="yardimci_oyuncu">Yardımcı oyuncu
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="stand_hostesi" name="field_kategorisi_value" value="stand_hostesi">Stand hostesi
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yesilcam" name="field_kategorisi_value" value="yesilcam">Yeşilçam
            <br>
        </fieldset>
        <label for="dob">Doğum Tarihi</label>
        <input type="date" id="dob" required name="field_dogum_tarihi_value" />
        <select id="height" required name="field_boy_value">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Boy -</option>
            <option value="150">1.50 - 1.60</option>
            <option value="160">1.61 - 1.70</option>
            <option value="170">1.71 - 1.80</option>
            <option value="180">1.81 - 1.90</option>
            <option value="190">1.91 - 2.00</option>
            <option value="200">2.01 - 2.10</option>
        </select>
        <select id="weight" required name="field_kilo_value">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Kilo -</option>
            <option value="45">40 - 50</option>
            <option value="55">51 - 60</option>
            <option value="65">61 - 70</option>
            <option value="75">71 - 80</option>
            <option value="85">81 - 90</option>
            <option value="95">91 - 100</option>
            <option value="105">101 - 110</option>
        </select>
        <select id="eyecolour" required name="field_goz_rengi_value" class="chosen-processed">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Göz rengi -</option>
            <option value="akahve">Açık kahve</option>
            <option value="kkahve">Koyu kahve</option>
            <option value="siyah">Siyah</option>
            <option value="mavi">Mavi</option>
            <option value="yesil">Yeşil</option>
            <option value="ela">Ela</option>
            <option value="gri">Gri</option>
        </select>
        <select id="skincolour" required name="field_ten_rengi_value" class="chosen-processed">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Ten rengi -</option>
            <option value="esmer">Esmer</option>
            <option value="beyaz">Beyaz</option>
            <option value="siyahi">Siyahi</option>
            <option value="bugday">Buğday</option>
        </select>
        <select id="shoesize" required name="field_ayak_no_value" class="chosen-processed">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Ayak no -</option>
            <option value="35">35</option>
            <option value="36">36</option>
            <option value="37">37</option>
            <option value="38">38</option>
            <option value="39">39</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
            <option value="41">41</option>
            <option value="42">42</option>
            <option value="43">43</option>
            <option value="44">44</option>
            <option value="45">45</option>
            <option value="46">46</option>
            <option value="47">47</option>
            <option value="48">48</option>
            <option value="49">49</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
        <select id="education" required name="field_egitim_duzeyi_value" class="chosen-processed">
            <option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Eğitim düzeyi -</option>
            <option value="İlkokul">İlkokul</option>
            <option value="Ortaokul">Ortaokul</option>
            <option value="Lise">Lise</option>
            <option value="Önlisans">Önlisans</option>
            <option value="Lisans">Lisans</option>
            <option value="Yüksek_lisans">Yüksek lisans</option>
            <option value="Doktora">Doktora</option>
        </select>
        <textarea id="training" placeholder="Oyunculuk eğitimleri" rows="3" name="field_oyunculuk_egitimleri_value"></textarea>
        <div class="description">Virgül ile ayırabilirsiniz</div>
        <input type="text" id="languages" placeholder="Diller" required name="field_diller_value" />
        <div class="description">Virgül ile ayırabilirsiniz</div>
        <input type="text" id="skills" placeholder="Beceriler" />
        <div class="description">Virgül ile ayırabilirsiniz</div>
        <input type="text" id="personal" placeholder="Kişisel" required name="field_kisisel_value" />
        <div class="description">Oyuncu hakkında biyografi niteliğinde bilgi</div>
        <legend>Yeni bir fotoğraf ekleyin</legend>
        <input type="file" id="images" />
        <input type="button" id="upload" value="Yükle" required/>
        <table id="prods">
            <tr class="prods">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="title" name="field_diskografi_value" placeholder="Yapım adı">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="prodtype" name="field_diskografi[und][0][value]">
                        <option selected disabled style="style:none;">- Yapım türü -</option>
                        <option value="dizi">Dizi</option>
                        <option value="film">Film</option>
                        <option value="klip">Klip</option>
                        <option value="reklam">Reklam</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="prodyear" name="field_diskografi[und][0][value]">
                        <option selected disabled style="style:none;">- Yapım yılı -</option>
                        <option value="2015">2015</option>
                        <option value="2014">2014</option>
                        <option value="2013">2013</option>
                        <option value="2012">2012</option>
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2010">2010</option>
                        <option value="2009">2009</option>
                        <option value="2008">2008</option>
                        <option value="2007">2007</option>
                        <option value="2006">2006</option>
                        <option value="2005">2005</option>
                        <option value="2004">2004</option>
                        <option value="2003">2003</option>
                        <option value="2002">2002</option>
                        <option value="2001">2001</option>
                        <option value="2000">2000</option>
                        <option value="1999">1999</option>
                        <option value="1998">1998</option>
                        <option value="1997">1997</option>
                        <option value="1996">1996</option>
                        <option value="1995">1995</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                        <option value="1989">1989</option>
                        <option value="1988">1988</option>
                        <option value="1987">1987</option>
                        <option value="1986">1986</option>
                        <option value="1985">1985</option>
                        <option value="1984">1984</option>
                        <option value="1983">1983</option>
                        <option value="1982">1982</option>
                        <option value="1981">1981</option>
                        <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        <option value="1979">1979</option>
                        <option value="1978">1978</option>
                        <option value="1977">1977</option>
                        <option value="1976">1976</option>
                        <option value="1975">1975</option>
                        <option value="1974">1974</option>
                        <option value="1973">1973</option>
                        <option value="1972">1972</option>
                        <option value="1971">1971</option>
                        <option value="1970">1970</option>
                        <option value="1969">1969</option>
                        <option value="1968">1968</option>
                        <option value="1967">1967</option>
                        <option value="1966">1966</option>
                        <option value="1965">1965</option>
                        <option value="1964">1964</option>
                        <option value="1963">1963</option>
                        <option value="1962">1962</option>
                        <option value="1961">1961</option>
                        <option value="1960">1960</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button id="addmoreprods">Başka bir öğe ekle</button>
        <label>Yer Aldığı Yapımlar</label>
        <label for="videos">Videolar</label>
        <table id="videos">
            <tr class="videos">
                <td>
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="text" class="videolink" placeholder="Video linki (Youtube, Vimeo)" />
                        <input type="text" class="videodesc" placeholder="Açıklama" />
                        <div class="description">Açıklama alanı aynı zamanda başlık olarak kullanılacaktır.</div>
                        <button id="addmorevideos">Başka bir öğe ekle</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="checkbox" id="privacy" value="0">
        <label for="privacy">Sayın üyemiz, başvuru formunda yer alan bilgiler, üçüncü şahıslar tarafından görüntülenmeyecektir. Lütfen <a href="inst.html" data-transition="pop" id="inst">başvuru talimatını</a> okuyunuz.</label> <a id="apply" data-role="button" class="hidden">Kaydol</a>

    </div>
    <div id="navHolder">
        <div id="homeHolder">
            <img id="homeBtn" src="img/homeBtn.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="loginHolder">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="notificationHolder">
            <div id="notification"></div>
            <img id="notificationBtn" src="img/notificationBtn.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**My Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("#profilepicture").on("change", function (e) {
        var ctx = $("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 300, 300);
            $("img").attr("src", img.src);
        }
    });
    $("#addmoreprods").on("click", function () {
        var tr = $(".prods").first().clone();
        tr.find('input').val('');
        $("#prods").append(tr);
    });
    $("#addmorevideos").on("click", function () {
        var tr = $(".videos").first().clone();
        tr.find('input').val('');
        $("#videos").append(tr);
    });
    /*$("#tel").mask("999 999-9999");
    $("#tel2").mask("999 999-9999");*/
    $("#privacy").on("change", function () {
        $("#submit").toggleClass("hidden");
    });
    $("a#inst").on('tap', function (event) {
        window.open('inst.html');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#apply").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.rejicast.com/services/user/token.json',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (token) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.rejicast.com/services/create.json',
                    type: 'post',
                    beforeSend: function (r) {
                        r.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token.token);
                    },
                    data: 'node[type]=oyuncu&node[status]=0&node[title]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#name").val()) + '&node[language]=und&node[field_tc_kimlik_no][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#tckn").val()) + '&node[field_sgk_durumu][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#sgk option:selected").val()) + '&node[field_telefon][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#tel").val()) + '&node[field_telefon_2][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#tel2").val()) + '&node[field_adres][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#address").val()) + '&node[field_yasadigi_sehir][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#city option:selected").val()) + '&node[field_kategorisi][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("input[name='kategori']:checked").val()) + '&node[field_dogum_tarihi][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#dob").val()) + '&node[field_boy][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("select#height option:checked").val()) + '&node[field_kilo][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("select#weight option:checked").val()) + '&node[field_goz_rengi][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("select#eyecolour option:checked").val()) + '&node[field_ten_rengi][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("select#skincolour option:checked").val()) + '&node[field_ayak_no][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("select#shoesize option:checked").val()) + '&node[field_egitim_duzeyi][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("select#education option:checked").val()) + '&node[field_oyunculuk_egitimleri][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#training").val()) + '&node[field_diller][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#languages").val()) + '&node[field_beceriler][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#skills").val()) + '&node[field_kisisel][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($("#personal").val()) + '&node[field_videolar[und][0][video_url]]=' + encodeURIComponent($(".videolink").val()) + '&node[field_videolar][und][0][description]=' + encodeURIComponent($(".videodesc").val()) + '&node[field_okudum_anladim][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent($(".privacy").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0),
                    success: function () {
                        window.location.href = "thanks.html";
                        /*
               $mobile.changePage("thanks.html", "slideup");
               */
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, message) {
                        console.log(message);
                        navigator.notification.alert("Kaydınızı oluşturamadık, daha sonra tekrar deneyin.");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

UPDATE: [This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/31486/17632) says I must build my form with Form API. Since I can't use it in my PG app, is that a fact?

UPDATE: One of the errors say "Non-allowed value in *Yaşadığı şehir* field. Based on your comment, please see a screenshot of allowed values of that field. Is that not correct?

[image: screenshot of allowed values list]

Comment: Have you use ajax drop down in your node content form?

Comment: You mean in the website? No, as far as I know.

Comment: Because if you use ajax drop down to populate dependent field it may return an illegal choice.

Comment: I'm not using ajax anywhere on the node form.

Comment: Without knowing what you mean, specifically, this is basically impossible to answer. For example, what data are you sending to what Drupal-based endpoint, what module is receiving and processing that data, what are you expecting to happen, and what actually happens (what's your payload, what resource are you consuming, what's the raw response)? Please make sure the code samples required to demonstrate the problem are included _in the question_, and not on a 3rd party website. Questions absolutely must be self-contained, so if 3rd party sites go down our repo of knowledge doesn't become useless

Comment: @Clive please see my edited question. I'm expecting to create a node. I get the `Illegal choice detected. Please contact site administrator` error for dropdowns instead. Text fields work just fine (tested).

Comment: Oh right, it's probably the age-old simple one - you're providing a value for a select list that isn't in the allowed values for that field. Drupal doesn't let you do that, as it's (correctly) considered an attack

Comment: @Clive please see my updated question, based on your comment.

Comment: I'd try `node[field_yasadigi_sehir][und][value]` or `node[field_yasadigi_sehir][0][value]` instead of `node[field_yasadigi_sehir][und][0][value]` in the JS; sometimes list fields can be funny. Otherwise the code does look correct at first glance. If neither of those work, check the browser console and see what the outgoing request actually contains - maybe the string value `09` is getting converted to an integer `9` along the way or something like that

Comment: @Clive you were right, `node[field_yasadigi_sehir][und][value]` worked :) If you could make that comment an answer, I want to accept it.

Comment: @Kartagis I will, but only once I've worked out _why_ it has to be this way :) It's actually been bugging me on and off for a couple of years, I've just never taken the time to work it out. Until then, I reckon you should save the bounty for anyone else who can come along and explain it!

Comment: Okay, but please make that an answer if nobody comes along and explains.

Comment: I will, just don't want to put off anyone else who has a better answer by seeing the checkmark next to it. If no one answers in a few days (or by the time I've worked it out) I'll put an answer in

Comment: As far as I've been able to determine this is just weirdness in the field api, but it seems that deltas are only valid for list field types that allow multiple values (which doesn't make any sense because the multiple values are still all going to be stored in the values array, not separately by delta).

Comment: And the fact that `<option selected disabled style="display:none;">- Yaşadığı şehir -</option>` has no "value" ?

Comment: @Clive bounty is ending in 8 hours, just so you know :)

Comment: @GregoryKapustin I fail to see any relevance.

Comment: Sorry @Kartagis, spaced on that. Haven't had time to look into it properly I'm afraid

Comment: Interesting @Trey, that does ring true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List fields can sometimes be a pain. Hopefully one day I'll work out why and update this, but in the meantime try addressing the field like this:

```
node[field_yasadigi_sehir][und][value]
```