# Drupal8: tableselect form element. Drupal::service('renderer')->render($element) return empty rows

Tags: 8

I have custom field widget with two fields:

- product_lines (checkboxes)
- sales_partners (tableselect)

I need to ajax-reload sales_partners tablesect values depending on product_lines input

In my Widget->formElement() i have:

```
...
$sp_table = $this->getSalespartnerTable($product_lines);

$element['product_lines'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => $this->t('Select product line'),
  '#default_value' => $product_lines,
  '#options' => $this->getProductLinesData(),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => [$this, 'updateSalesPartnersTable'],
  ),
);
$element['sales_partners'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $sp_table['header'],
  '#default_value' => $sales_partners,
  '#options' => $sp_table['options'],
  '#empty' => $this->t('No sales partners found'),
);
...
```

in Widget->updateSalesPartnersTable($product_lines) I have:

```
...
$table_data = $this->getSalespartnerTable($allowed_product_lines);
$sp_field = &$form['field_access_settings']['widget'][0]['sales_partners'];
$sp_field['#options'] = $table_data;
$sp_field = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($sp_field);

$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#edit-field-access-settings-0-sales-partners', $sp_field));
return $response;
```

So, I use the same function to generate values array for tableselect and I am sure it returns valid data. The widget works fine on initial page load:
[image]

but when the salespartners table is reloaded by ajax it displays empty rows:
[image]

The culprit, I think, is this string (returns empty table rows despite valid $sp_field table array):

```
$sp_field = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($sp_field);
```

but I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/how-can-i-implement-ajax-form-submission/188752#188752

Comment: Thanks, @IvanJaros , but there's nothing to do with ajax itself, it works fine