# AJAX replaced elements not able to callback

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a form with AJAX elements, generated as follows:

```
    $memberForm['members'] = [
      '#prefix' => '<div id="'.$id.'">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];
    $form['members']['extra_flag1'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $config->get('extras.flag1'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => [$this, 'updateMemberOptionFields'],
        'event' => 'change',
      ),
    ];
```

(There are other fields displayed based on the current value of the checkbox).

My callback function looks like this:

```
  public function updateMemberOptionFields(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#extra_flag1_1', render($form['members']['member1']['extra_flag1'])));

    return $ajax_response;
  }
```

This works perfectly the first time the checkbox is clicked, but subsequent clicks have no effect.

I have other AJAX components that use the #wrapper property, and these work fine. However, this component will need to replace multiple sections in different parts of the form.

Is there a way the replacement elements can have AJAX callbacks?

Thanks!

James

Comment: I feel like this has to do with the form needing to be rebuilt.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/how-can-i-implement-ajax-form-submission/188752#188752

Comment: That checklist is very helpful. I was able to use getTriggeringElement to find out which checkbox triggered the Ajax call, and that meant I only need to replace one part of the form, so I could change the form to only replace to part associated with the checkbox that was actually clicked.