# Ajax Form submit doesn't work second time

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I'm loading the node/edit form in a block and I add ajax on submit.

I add the Ajax in the hook_form_alter.

```
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="' . $form_wrapper . '">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'submitForm';
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'my_ajax_callback',
  'wrapper' => $form_wrapper,
  'effect' => 'fade',
);
```

The SubmitForm:

```
function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
  $input = $form_state->getUserInput();
  $form_state->setUserInput($input);
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
}
```

And the callback :

```
function my_ajax_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   $form_state->setRebuild();
   return $form;
}
```

The first time works fine. The second time seems to work without any error but it doesn't submit my new data.

I checked this comment [How can I implement AJAX form submission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/how-can-i-implement-ajax-form-submission/188752#188752) but I don't know if I have to set the values to the form_state. Also i use this callback for multiple content types. Should I check and set the value for each field? Is there a better way?

Thanks for your help!

------ EDIT -----

I added the submitForm function and now the second time I submit I get 'The content has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications. As a result, your changes cannot be saved.'.

Also, should I get/set each one of my fields or $input = $form_state->getUserInput(); $form_state->setUserInput($input); are enough?

-------- UPDATE ------

I managed to make it work for forms that I need to be empty after the ajax submit using the below code :

In hook_form_alter:

```
$form['wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('id' => $form_wrapper),
  );

$prefix = '<div id="' . $form_wrapper . '">';
$form['#prefix'] = $prefix;
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\Form\FormAlter::ajaxFormEntityFormSubmitEmptyForm';
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
    'callback' => 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\Form\FormAlter::ajaxFormEntityCallbackEmptyForm',
    'wrapper' => $form_wrapper,
    'effect' => 'fade',
);
```

And in the FormAlter.php :

```
/**
 * Rebuild the form - Empty form.
 */
 public static function ajaxFormEntityFormSubmitEmptyForm($form, &$form_state){
  $entity = $form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->getEntity();
  $entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
  $bundle = $entity->bundle();
  $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->create(['type' => $bundle]);
  $form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->setEntity($new_entity);

  // Clear user input.
  $input = $form_state->getUserInput();
  $clean_keys = $form_state->getCleanValueKeys();
  $clean_keys[] = 'ajax_page_state';
  foreach ($input as $key => $item) {
    if (!in_array($key, $clean_keys) && substr($key, 0, 1) !== '_') {
      unset($input[$key]);
    }
  }

  $input['entity'] = $entity;
  $form_state->setUserInput($input);

  // Rebuild the form state values.
  $form_state->setRebuild();
  $form_state->setStorage([]);
}

/**
 * Ajax callback to handle just returns the form
 */
 public static function ajaxFormEntityCallbackEmptyForm(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
     return $form;
   }
   else {
     return $form;
    }
  }
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar but I want the form populated with the new values. So I created two new functions in FormAlter:

```
 /**
  * Rebuild the form.
  */
  public static function ajaxFormEntityFormSubmit($form, &$form_state) {
    $entity = $form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->getEntity();
    $entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
    $bundle = $entity->bundle();

    $new_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->create(['type' => $bundle]);
    $form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->setEntity($new_entity);

    $input = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $input['entity'] = $entity;

    $form_state->setUserInput($input);
    if(!$form_state->hasValue('title')){
      $form_state->setValue('title',$entity->getTitle());
    }

    // Rebuild the form state values.
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
    $form_state->setStorage([]);
  }

 /**
  * Ajax callback to handle special ajax form entity magic.
  */
  public static function ajaxFormEntityCallback(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // If errors, returns the form with errors and messages.
  if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
    return $form;
  }
  // Else show the result.
  else {
    $userInputs = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $entity = $userInputs['entity'];
    $entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    if ($entity_type == 'node') {
      $title = $entity->getTitle();
    }
    return $form;
  }
}
```

If I return the $form in the callback, the first time works fine but the second I'm getting two errors in the log:

> Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title'
>   cannot be null: INSERT INTO {node_field_data} (nid, vid, type,
>   langcode, status, title, uid, created, changed, promote, sticky,
>   revision_translation_affected, default_langcode) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_12); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 201
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 258 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   my_estate_details [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => en
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =>
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 5 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] =>
>   1500889059 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 1500889066
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 1 ) in
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->handleQueryException()

And

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO
>   {node_field_data} (nid, vid, type, langcode, status, title, uid,
>   created, changed, promote, sticky, revision_translation_affected,
>   default_langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 201 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 258
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => my_estate_details
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => en [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 5
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1500889059 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] =>
>   1500889066 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_10]
>   => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 1 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save()

In case I return $response (which is what I prefer in order to be able to alter the message etc), the first time works fine but the second I get the message:

> The content has either been modified by another user, or you have
>   already submitted modifications. As a result, your changes cannot be
>   saved.'.

Apologies for the long message. Any idea/help will be helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: re-read my comment(the one you linked), you've missed a lot of stuff.

Comment: Should I also add a submit handler except the callback? I think I'm pretty confused. Could you give me some more details please?

Comment: I also added $input = $form_state->getUserInput();  $form_state->setUserInput($input); in order to get the user input and set it in the $form_state. Is that correct? After that I do the $form_state->setRebuild(); and then return $form;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution.

In my hook_form_alter :

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = $ajax_id;
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\Form\FormAlter::ajaxFormEntityFormSubmit';
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'Drupal\MY_MODULE\Plugin\Form\FormAlter::ajaxFormEntityCallback',
  'wrapper' => $ajax_id,
  'effect' => 'fade',
);
$form['ajax_form_entity'] = [
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => [
    'reload' => '.reload',
    'form_selector' => '.' . $ajax_id,
    'show_message' => TRUE,
  ]
];

public static function ajaxFormEntityFormSubmit($form, &$form_state) {
    $entity = $form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->getEntity();

    // Clear user input.
    $input = $form_state->getUserInput();
    // We should not clear the system items from the user input.
    $clean_keys = $form_state->getCleanValueKeys();
    $clean_keys[] = 'ajax_page_state';
    foreach ($input as $key => $item) {
      if (!in_array($key, $clean_keys) && substr($key, 0, 1) !== '_') {
        unset($input[$key]);
      }
    }

    // Store new entity for display in the AJAX callback.
    $input['entity'] = $entity;
    $form_state->setUserInput($input);

    // Rebuild the form state values.
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    $form_state->setStorage([]);
  }
```

And the callback:

```
public static function ajaxFormEntityCallback(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // If errors, returns the form with errors and messages.
    if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
      return $form;
    }
    // Else show the result.
    else {
      $userInputs = $form_state->getUserInput();
      $entity = $userInputs['entity'];
      $entity_type = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
      $configurations = $form_state->getValue('ajax_form_entity');

      $response = new AjaxResponse();

      // Get messages even if not shown.
      $status_messages = array('#type' => 'status_messages');
      $message = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($status_messages);

      // Reload the form.
        $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand($configurations['form_selector'], $form));

      return $response;
    }
  }
```