# Simple AJAX callback fired on form submission button click

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I am trying to fire an AJAX callback when the user presses the submit button. This is such a simple thing but trying to debug Drupal's Form AJAX API is driving me crazy. At this point I just need a fresh set of eyes to look over it. Currently, when I press the button the page just refreshes and the AJAX callback is never fired. I have a form being built with the following code:

```
class OnlineRevenueForm extends FormBase {
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['resetbutton'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        '#prefix' => '<div class="buttons">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'Drupal\revenue_projection_model\Controller\RPMController::ResetFields',
            'event' => 'click',
            'progress' => array(
                'type' => 'throbber',
                'message' => NULL,
            ),
        )
    );
    return $form;
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRebuild(FALSE);
  }
}
```

Inside of my controller I load this form using the following code:

```
class RPMController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {
 public function rpm() {
    // Load the module's template file
    $TemplateFilePath = drupal_get_path('module', 'revenue_projection_model') . "/templates/revenue_projection_model.html.twig";
    $template = $this->twig->loadTemplate($TemplateFilePath);
    //Load Forms
    $OnlineRevForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\revenue_projection_model\Form\OnlineRevenueForm');
        $markup = [
         '#type' => 'inline_template',
         '#template' => $template->render(
            ['online_rev_form' => $OnlineRevForm]
         )
        ];
   return $markup;
 }
```

This form is then displayed via the twig template file. The callback that I'm trying to call is also inside of the Controller:

```
public static function ResetFields(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
     $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
     $ajax_response -> addCommand(new AlertCommand("Testing"));
     return $ajax_response;
}
```

**Update 1:**
I have updated how the form is being return in the controller. It is now being returned as a unrendered form in a render array.

```
public function rpm() {
  $OnlineRevForm = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\revenue_projection_model\Form\OnlineRevenueForm');
  return [
        '#theme' => 'rpm_page',
        '#online_rev_form' => $OnlineRevForm
  ];
}
```

I have also added this code to the .module file:

```
function revenue_projection_model_theme() {
  $theme['rpm_page'] = [
    'variables' => ['online_rev_form' => NULL],
    'template' => 'revenue_projection_model',
  ];

  return $theme;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a form route `_form: Drupal\example\Form\ExampleForm` instead of a controller?

Comment: @4k4 There is more logic going on the page that is unrelated to the said form. Whether I'm using a controller or just a form route, I should still be able to fire the callback from the form.

Comment: No, this can't work. You lose the attachments of the form on the way and without the attached libraries there is no ajax. Don't render the form, the controller should return it unrendered. If you use a twig template, then build a render array for it, with the form placed unrendered in a template variable.

Comment: @4k4 I have updated the code to include the suggestions that you made. unfortunately, I'm running into the same problem. Any suggestions or ways to better debug this?

Comment: The controller looks good now. I think you should see some progress with the ajax js libraries. You can check this in the browser debugging tools, before and after you've changed the controller.

Comment: Remove the 'click' event.

Answer (score 2):

You also need a submit function.

You can have a look [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238799/ajax-form-submit-doesnt-work-second-time). It's a complete example with submit handler and callback. In this case I altered the form as I didn't create it but is quite similar. Also a really nice post is [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/how-can-i-implement-ajax-form-submission/188752#188752)

Comment: I should have made note of that in the original post. I do have a submit form function already defined. I have updated the post to reflect this.