# Form field name not rendered after submit the form

Tags: 8, forms

I created a form and designed it by referred this [link](https://www.foreach.be/blog/how-manipulate-forms-drupal-8). It worked fine. I used the following code to display a textbox in my form

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {    
    $form['searchtext'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Keyword Search:'),
          //'#default_value' => (isset($record['searchtext'])) ? $record['searchtext']:'',
          '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Enter keyword to assist locating notices relevant to your vehicle')),
        );
    $form['#theme'] = ['notices_search_form'];
    //echo "before submit: <pre>";print_r($form);echo "</pre>";
    return $form;
}
```

and it is rendered correctly as i expected as below (it has name, id and everything)

```
<input placeholder="Enter keyword to assist locating notices relevant to your vehicle" data-drupal-selector="edit-searchtext" type="text" id="edit-searchtext" name="searchtext" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
```

But after submitting the form, I stop the redirection and load the form with the value entered while submitting form using following code

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $fieldvalues=$form_state->getValues();
    $form['searchtext']['#value'] = (isset($fieldvalues['searchtext'])) ? $fieldvalues['searchtext']:'';
    $form_state->disableRedirect();
    return $form;
  }
```

But this time form loads without name or id as below

```
<input placeholder="Enter keyword to assist locating notices relevant to your vehicle" type="text" value="sdfdf" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
```

I am new to drupal. Someone suggest me what am i missing?

**Edit 1**

I tried to place the name in the array like below and it is worked fine.

```
$form['searchtext'] = array(
      '#name' => 'searchtext',
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Keyword Search:'),
      //'#default_value' => (isset($record['searchtext'])) ? $record['searchtext']:'',
      '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => t('Enter keyword to assist locating notices relevant to your vehicle')),
    );
```

But setting 'true' to  "#default_value" for checkbox field is not checking while rendering it.

Comment: Your submit handler is wrong. You have to use ajax. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188730/how-can-i-implement-ajax-form-submission/188752#188752

Comment: @IvanJaros, the submit handler looks a bit odd, because normally it doesn't return $form, but in general it's OK to rebuild forms without ajax.

Comment: Actually i never had to do anything. After removing `$form['searchtext']['#value'] = (isset($fieldvalues['searchtext'])) ? $fieldvalues['searchtext']:'';` this line it works perfectly. Form takes the submitted value by default. 
But still have a question. After an attribute has been added to an existing element, why the form does not render the name of that element?