# $form_state['values'] AJAX

Tags: forms, ajax

I have the following form: 
**Displayed at Page load**

```
$form['platform'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select a Platform'),
  '#options' => array(
    0 => t('- Select -')) + $options,
  '#default_value' =>  0,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_select_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'replace_model_div',
    'effect' => 'slide',
   ),
);
```

I'm trying to pull out the `$form_state['values']` to determine if another select field should be shown. However I'm not sure how this will ever get called without a submit function.

**To be Displayed after option is selected**

```
 if (isset($form_state['values']['platform'])) {
 $platform_value = $form_state['values']['platform'];
 $sqlmodel = "SELECT tid, name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE vid = $platform_value";
 $result = db_query($sqlmodel);
 $options = array();
   foreach ($result as $row) {
     $model_options[$row->vid] = t($row->name);
    }

$form['model_wrapper'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select a Model'),
  '#options' => $model_options,
  '#options' => t('$platform_value'),
  '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_model_div">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
}
return $form;
}
function ajax_select_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['model_wrapper'];
}
```

If I am understanding AJAX properly even though on a select change my AJAX call will happen to render the `model_wrapper`. There is nothing in the AJAX call that will re-evaluate the `if (isset` function, and as such the `model_wrapper` section will never display.

Full story and objective: [AJAX dependent select](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35202/ajax-dependent-select)

Comment: have you tried your code? because i can't see anything wrong with it

Comment: @MariusIlie Indeed I have. When I make a select from the Platform select box it kicks off the AJAX call however the Model select box never appears.

Comment: What do you plan to do with your form if not submit it?

Comment: @Clive there will be a submit handler, but my hope was to have the form build itself out as the user fills it in. As the list of models is dependent on what they end up selecting in the Platform field.

Comment: I haven't tested the code but if the missing submit button is causing you problems, why not just include it anyway but set it to `#disabled` until the rest of the form has been added? That'll achieve the same effect, and you can even hide it via css until it's ready if you really don't want to display it

Comment: @Clive well that's more speculation on my part than anything else. Will not having a submit button on the page break the AJAX call from re-evaluating the `if isset` logic there by not ever rendering the Model select list?

Comment: Don't know...will put your code in a module quickly and find out

Comment: Turns it out it's nothing to do with the submit button, I've added an answer which should solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because the `<div>` with an ID of `replace_model_div` doesn't exist when the form is first built. So when the AJAX replace happens, there's no target container to append it to.

All you need to do is re-structure you form slightly (and remove the second `#options` array added to the second select):

```
$form['model_wrapper_container'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_model_div">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);

if (isset($form_state['values']['platform'])) {
  $platform_value = $form_state['values']['platform'];
  $sqlmodel = "SELECT tid, name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} WHERE vid = $platform_value";
  $result = db_query($sqlmodel);
  $model_options = array();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $model_options[$row->vid] = t($row->name);
  }

  $form['model_wrapper_container']['model_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select a Model'),
    '#options' => $model_options,
  );
}
```

And a small change to the callback:

```
function ajax_select_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['model_wrapper_container'];
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense and closes out both my issues. I get it now, basically I must form a container that will first be rendered on page load and then within that container I can have my if isset logic. Which will be overwritten via the AJAX call. Thank you very much!