# How to create dependent dropdown in drupal 7 content type?

Tags: nodes

I have created a 2 custome content type in drupal 7 one is tourname and another one is location. Once I added a tour name in tour content type like tour1,tour2 and so on. In location content type I added location1, location 2 and so on for each tour name. Now I created third content type name it as details in that I need two drop down one is list of tour I have added and another one is list of location I have inserted. Whenever i changed the tour drop down value, the second drop down value will get automatically updated  based on the tour name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168532/how-to-create-dependent-dropdown-in-drupal-7-content-type). Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a tour and location used **Node reference module**. And automatically change the drop down  option value of location based on tour option value that you can use ajax .  following url help to u

[Dynamic select list in the form (dependent dropdown)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown)

https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/function/ajax_example_dependent_dropdown/7

Comment: Hello. Links may be helpful, but assume they are down, for any reason. Do you think your answer would still be useful?.. It would be better to provide excerpts, quotes or instructions based on linked content, so your answer would have a value on it's own.

Comment: yes, Already I used that link for my task on some last days.That only i mentioned - molot