# Adding Ajax on existing dropdown list

Tags: ajax, forms

I added this code in my template.php

```
function PORTO_SUB_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'rapporto_di_lavoro_node_form') {

    $form['field_livello']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
                                  'callback' => 'my_test_callback',
                                  'wrapper' => 'callback_wrapper',
                                  'progress' => array(
                                    'message' => 'caricamento',
                                    'type' => 'throbber',
                                    ),
                                );        }}

function my_test_callback($form, &$form_state) {
dpm($form_state); 
}
```

When I select an item I can see the throbble, but no dpm() message.
What's wrong?

As I'm still not modifying fields, I don't need to unset or indicate wrapper, aren’t I?

Answer (score 0):

similar question is here.

[Dynamic select list in the form (dependent dropdown)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown)

you can get your solution from here.

Comment: I started here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSg2uNs8L3g and read it twice, but no lamp turn on in my head :(

Comment: the you-tube video is good, i think you are missing something

Comment: Should be nice to find what I'm missing! Thnaks anyway!