# How to get selected Value in the listbox by using form api

Tags: forms, ajax

I have created a form with fields titled State and City. After selecting the state's appropriate city records, they will be loaded into city listbox. Until now they were working fine, but after clicking the submit button I am not able to store the city's value into variable called `$data1`. How can I get it to return the city value?

Source code

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $query_state=db_select('state', 's');
  $query_state->fields('s',array('State_code','State_name'));
  $query_state->orderBy('State_name','ASC');
  $state_results = $query_state->execute();
  $options_state = array();

  foreach($state_results as $state_record) {
    $options_state[$state_record->State_code]=t($state_record->State_name);
  }

  $form['state1']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#options' =>$options_state,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
      'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
    ),
  );


  $form['city_element_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

Ajax Function

```
function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state) { 
  $key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;

  $query_city=db_select('city', 'c');
  $query_city->fields('c',array('District_Code','District_Name','State_Code'));
  $query_city->condition('State_Code', $key, '=');

  $query_city->orderBy('District_Name','ASC');
  $city_results = $query_city->execute();
  $options_city = array();


  foreach ($city_results as $city_record) {
    // This is correct.
    $options_city[$city_record->District_Code]=t($city_record->District_Name);
  }

  $form['city_element_wrapper']['city']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('District'),
    '#options' => $options_city,
    '#required' => TRUE,);

  return $form['city_element_wrapper']; 
}
```

Now I am trying to store the value of what I have selected in City listbox into `$data1` variable but I am not able to store it, Please guide me how to store. It is printing empty value (i.e blank)

```
function form_test_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $data1 = $form_state['values']['city_element_wrapper'];
  print_r($data1); // it is printing empty value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try `form_test_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {}`

2) Try to print all values. `print_r($form_state['values']);`

> // $form_state['values']['city']; you may get values here.

You can write `$form['city_element_wrapper']['city']` array inside the `form_test_form` itself, instead of writing inside ajax callback.

Comment: I have tried this print_r($form_state['values']); but city values not displaying.  I dont know how to write ajax call back inside the form_test_form. can you send me suggestions

Comment: $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => t('Save Settings'),
  ); include it in form

Comment: @balakrishnan: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown

Comment: Refer this too: http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-ajax-dropdown-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks @kalidasan, I tried w2shamna.com demo but not working please check demo link. can you give me ur mail id please

Comment: @balakrishnan: I have shared it for example purpose. Busy in project, not able to prepare example for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $query_state=db_select('state', 's');
  $query_state->fields('s',array('State_code','State_name'));
  $query_state->orderBy('State_name','ASC');
  $state_results = $query_state->execute();
  $options_state = array();

  foreach($state_results as $state_record) {
    $options_state[$state_record->State_code]=t($state_record->State_name);
  }

  $form['state1']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#options' =>$options_state,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
      'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
    ),
  );


  $form['city_element_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  // Submit Button
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

  return $form;
}
form_test_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
print_r($form_state['values'])
}
```

Try this