# States with a variable

Tags: 7, forms

I have to do a form and in this form I have a select to choose a value, from this value I load a node and from this node I get a boolean.

With this boolean I have to show or not another form field, but I don't find the way to do this.

First I try to add an `#access` to the field I need to show or not, and the access value is defined by this : `$access = ($is_liberte ? TRUE : FALSE);`

And here is the form element :

```
$form['info_voyage']['order_id'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Order ID'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#access' => $access
);
```

And to reload this I try to add a callback on the first field with this function :

```
function _ga_facture_date_callback($form, $form_state){
  return $form['info_voyage']["product_id"];
}
```

This function reload the form (I think), when I change the field with the callback the function is called and the form is recalculated, so my access value change in the form field but the field doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

I also think to do a states on the field to show but I have searched and I doesn't find any way to do a form states with a variable, and not another field.

Comment: Why are you returning `product_id` when you've changed `order_id`?

Comment: It's my first field, it's a select and in this select I choose a product, when I select an item I return this to 'reload' the form, and I use the product_id to load some orders to add them in the `order_id` field and change the access to TRUE. The access is changed but the form is not refresh so the field doesn't appear, and I don't know how to do this without reloading the page

Comment: The AJAX callback needs to return the element that has changed, not the element that triggered the change. Similarly the wrapper around product_id needs to match the wrapper in the `#ajax` property in the order_id element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic select list in the form (dependent dropdown)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/dynamic-select-list-in-the-form-dependent-dropdown)

Comment: It's not a direct dependent dropdown, but thanks @Clive I found the solution (I wrap my product_id and order_id) and return the wrapper in the ajax

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the node IDs for the primary select are known or can be retrieved dynamically following some conditions, you can use the following pattern to display and populate the secondary select conditionally.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $options = [];

  $nodes = node_load_multiple([
    '70',
    '71',
    '72',
    '73',
    '74',
    '75',
  ]);

  foreach ($nodes as $product) {
    $options[$product->nid] = $product->title;
  }

  $form['node_select'] = [
    '#type'    => 'select',
    '#title'   => t('Select a node'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#ajax'    => [
      'callback' => '_secondary_select_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper'  => 'foo-bar',
    ],
  ];

  // You need a wrapper to provide a HTML ID to be targeted by the callback.
  $form['secondary_select_wrapper'] = [
    '#type'       => 'container',
    '#attributes' => ['id' => 'foo-bar'],
  ];

  // The secondary select is hidden initially.
  $form['secondary_select_wrapper']['secondary_select'] = [
    '#type'    => 'select',
    '#title'   => t('Select a value'),
    '#options' => [],
    '#access'  => FALSE,
  ];

  $form['submit_button'] = [
    '#type'  => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
  ];

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Secondary Select AJAX Callback.
 */
function _secondary_select_ajax_callback(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $options = [];
  $nid = $form_state['values']['node_select'];
  $node = node_load($nid);

  // Do whatever you need to do to populate your options.
  // ...

  $form['secondary_select_wrapper']['secondary_select']['#access'] = TRUE;
  $form['secondary_select_wrapper']['secondary_select']['#options'] = $options;

  return $form['secondary_select_wrapper'];
}
```

Comment: I can't do like that because I use the value from the select to load a node, and from this node I get the value to use.

Comment: @JessyChenavas – Answer updated. Use the callback to conditionally display and populate the secondary select by retrieving the primary select's node id.